# XAML DataGrid with MultiSelect ComboBox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the following DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" mah:DataGridHelper.EnableCellEditAssist="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvent, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrItem.Events, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" AllowDrop="False" AutomationProperties.Name="Events" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="AuxDate" Binding="{Binding AuxDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Location" Binding="{Binding Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tags" Width="140">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}, Mode=OneWay, Path=DataContext.Tags}">
                                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" Unchecked="Tag_unchecked" Checked="Tag_checked" Tag="{Binding Id}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The desired behaviour is to have a muti-select combo-box of all tags for each row separately. I have a problem finding a way to bind it to viewModel. My current solution is the following ugly workaround:

```
    public Item CurrItem { get; set; }
    private ArchivatorDbContext _context { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; }
    public EventEntity SelectedEvent { get; set; }

    public void AddTag(int TagId)
    {
        if (SelectedEvent == null) return;

        _context.Add(new Event2Tag(){Tag = _context.Tags.Find(TagId), Event = SelectedEvent});
    }

    public void RemoveTag(int TagId)
    {
        if (SelectedEvent == null) return;
        _context.Remove(SelectedEvent.Tags.First(tag => tag.TagId == TagId));
        SelectedEvent.Tags.Remove(SelectedEvent.Tags.First(tag => tag.TagId == TagId));
    }
```

The main problem with this approach is that I use the same page for editing items, by swapping new Item in viewModel for the edited one, but because of how this works the tags do not get set, as they are not directly bound to items. I would also prefer to use dataBinding instead of code, but I will take any solution that works.

For some reason DataGridTemplateColumn does not recieve item from its current row, unlike DataGridTextColumn, what am I doing wrong? And is there by any chance a library to make this easier?
Thanks

Extra info:

- The app is a WPF app with entity framework
- All dependencies are latest stable releases
- I am using visual studio with ReSharper and blend

Comment: *For some reason DataGridTemplateColumn does not recieve item from its current row, unlike DataGridTextColumn...* Yes, it does. What exactly is your issue? Is the `DataGrid` hosted in a `Page`?

Comment: @mm8 Yes it is, when I tried to databind directly to the item intellisense kicked in saying it is not recognised in current context, and the only context available was viewModel itself

Comment: Then the intellisense is wrong. What matters is whether it works at *runtime*?

Comment: @mm8 But it does not work, the item does not get bound and I get a warning that context is not available

Comment: Is the `Tag` property defined in the same class as `Name`, `Description`, `Date` and the other properties? Or where it is defined and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Item contains(0-to-many) events, event has m-to-m to tags. I want a multi select combo list that if checked adds the tag to relationship with specific event.